# mysql extract year from date format

Tags: mysql

I need a mysql query to extract the year from the following date format from a table in my database.

For eg :

```
        subdateshow
      ----------------      
        01/17/2009
        01/17/2009
        01/17/2009
        01/17/2009
        01/17/2009
```

the following query didn't working

```
select YEAR ( subdateshow ) from table
```

The column type is varchar. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Since your subdateshow is a VARCHAR column instead of the proper [DATE, TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html) you have to convert the string to date before you can use YEAR on it:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(subdateshow, "%m/%d/%Y")) from table
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: how to put a parameter where in that select `where year = X`

Comment: can you check this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204869/mysql-php-pdo-select-a-part-of-row-value-date-record?noredirect=1#comment50412416_31204869

Answer (score 22):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM subdateshow) FROM tbl_name;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM field) FROM table WHERE id=1
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(subdateshow, '%m/%d/%Y')) FROM table;
```

eg:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('01/17/2009', '%m/%d/%Y'));  /* shows "2009" */
```

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(field), '%Y') FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work if the date format is consistent:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX( subdateshow,"/",-1 ) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (STR_TO_DATE(subdateshow, '%d/%m/%Y')));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

`SELECT YEAR( str_to_date( subdateshow, '%m/%d/%Y' ) ) AS Mydate`