# add one year, to a year in the where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this table called "event" and the column "year":

```
year
-----------
2013.01.01
2014.03.01
2015.02.03
```

How can I query something like this in the where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM event 
WHERE  year>=2013 to year<=year+1;
```

(so "year + 1" should give me 2014  ) i don't need the date and month.

Thank you.

Comment: Your `year` column is a `date` format, right? If not, you need to change it. Then you can use `DATEADD` to add your year.

Comment: Yes it's a date format, and no I can't change it I'm not allowed. And dateadd() doesn't work :(

Comment: Is the data type of your column `date` or a text type like `varchar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide the year twice, as a parameter, which you should be using anyway:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE YEAR(year) >= ? AND YEAR(year) <= ?+1
```

Why you're calling a date column 'year' when it contains an entire date is a mystery. It would remove confusion if you gave it a proper name.

Comment: Yea thank you for the advice and the answer, the real name of the column is in german, and it's a very long name, Thank you EJP

Answer (score -1):

It's same to [mysql extract year from date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712771/mysql-extract-year-from-date-format).

You need to write smth like:

```
SELECT *, YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(year, "%Y.%m.%d")) as year2 FROM event 
WHERE  year2 >= 2013 AND year2 <= year2 + 1;
```

Frankly speaking, misuderstand what should do "year>=2013 to year<=year+1;", but now in column year2 may be correct year, extracted from date.

Enjoy! :)

Comment: 'year2 <= year2+1' is a pointless tautology. The STRTODATE() is fairly pointless too.