# Get Year from complete data filter year

Tags: php, mysql, return

I have a data in my db, like:

```
2016-05-17     ,     2015-05-20    ,    2015-02-02
```

I want to get only the years to create a list, like:

```
2016 , 2015
```

I'm making this:

```
SELECT * FROM insercao GROUP BY SUBSTR(data,0,4)
```

But this return only:

```
2015
```

How can I return All not duplicated years?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTR(data,0,4)) FROM insercao`

Comment: Are you storing comma delimited values in a single row or are the dates stored in multiple rows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712771/mysql-extract-year-from-date-format

Comment: I'm using fetch_assoc PHP to get data.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is a *datetime* field, you ahve to change your query in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM insercao GROUP BY YEAR(`data`)
```

#### Edit:

In fact, to return only year value, you have to act in this way:

```
SELECT YEAR(`time`) as year FROM insercao GROUP BY year
```

Comment: @user3664644 what type if your `data`? (Please also note that in my answer there are a typo: remove the space after `data`)

Comment: my db type is data. Yes i remove'd the space

Comment: type `data`? type `date`. It doesn't work because it doesn't return the year or because return only one row? See my modified answer for this

Comment: Doesn't return anything

Comment: If it doesn't return anything, you have a problem with your code or with your db. double-check it. I have tested my two solutions with **datetime and date** fields and they works.

Answer (score 0):

`select distinct EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_column_name) FROM date_extract;`

The extract keyword of MYSQL extracts years form the date format that you mentioned in question.
Distinct will only select non repeating years.

Comment: are you sure? i just tried it :( data screenshot: http://imgur.com/nULvXs5 query result screenshot: http://imgur.com/cw0XHz6 let me know if i m getting ur question wrong.