# How to get Data from specified 'Year' where the 'Year' is DATETIME Column

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I would like to get every data from a table where the year is specified. But the problem is i put my date in DATETIME type.

I'm trying something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    entrytime = 2017 //entrytime is datetime type.
```

But, it's wrong.

Is there any way to get the data or maybe a better approach ?

Thank you.

Comment: The manual is a great source of information https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql extract year from date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712771/mysql-extract-year-from-date-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use year function on datetime:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE year(entrytime) = 2017
```

or better:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE entrytime >= '2017-01-01'
AND entrytime < '2018-01-01'
```

The latter can make use of index if present on the entrytime column, which can make your query run faster.

Comment: The latter is so much better than the former, I’d be tempted to forget about the former altogether

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`year`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function to extract the year of a `datetime`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  YEAR(entrytime) = 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the YEAR function, theres a document on it [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-year-function.php).

So...

```
SELECT
*
FROM Table
WHERE YEAR(DateColumn) = 2017
```

Comment: better point to [_**mysql site for documentation**_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year).