# Specific date with current_month and previous_month

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Is it possible to make the year and month part of the date dynamic (based on current year and month) instead of hard coded?

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`)
FROM employees 
WHERE (`date` between "2018-08-26" and "2018-09-26") AND `status` = 'Pending';
```

In the above example, if the current month is `9` then the query should be `08-26` and `09-26`, if the current month is `10` then `09-26` and `10-26` and so on.

Comment: not clear what you ask?

Comment: You want the current date and time?

Comment: @TheHive what is the datatype of `date` column? string or datetime?

Comment: @AbhishekKeshri `date`

Comment: @TheHive As i understood it, the 1st date will be given (user, some input etc) and we will derive the 2nd date using that. Right?

Comment: Yes `26` is static and the rest is dynamic.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: You can use `Year` and `month` on your input date, then use `cases` as corner cases would be related to month of december for which you will need to change the year. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712771/mysql-extract-year-from-date-format

Comment: You have used all three quotes. Don't do that. Avoid `"` for strings.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can build the desired dates:

```
SELECT 
    CURRENT_DATE,
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), 26), '%Y-%m-%d'),
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), 26), '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
-- 2018-09-25 | 2018-09-26 | 2018-08-26
```

And use the above in your query:

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`)
FROM employees 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), 26), '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), 26), '%Y-%m-%d')
AND `status` = 'Pending';
```

Comment: God bless you! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to query data for last month, it's enough to use such query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE some_datetime_column > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH);
```

Also, if you want to get current month/year, try this:

```
SELECT MONTH(NOW()), YEAR(NOW())
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5KXjpX7nifeJY8Kr1efqwU/0)

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
--here you specify the day of the month you want
SELECT @days := 26 - DAY(NOW());
SELECT @startDate := DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL @days DAY),
       @endDate := DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CAST(NOW() AS DATE), INTERVAL @days DAY), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
```

[Another demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5KXjpX7nifeJY8Kr1efqwU/1)

Then you can use it like:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE date_column BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Comment: I want to specify a fixed date.

Comment: @TheHive Either you want it dynamic or static... Fixed is static, you asked for dynamic interval.

Comment: Only the date is static, 26th.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn OP wants 1st field to be fixed, which will be inputted by the user etc, and 2nd field will be derived from that. Your code fails to do that.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn how do you select the rows `* FROM t1`

Comment: I am sorry, i have not used this before, how do i query this and output as while loop in php

Comment: @TheHive I don't know PHP. You have query you can use, I can't help you any more.

Answer (score 1):

Try below with now() and last month (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)):

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM employees 
WHERE (`date` between DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and now())
AND `status` = 'Pending';
```

Answer (score 0):

To Get Current Month use

```
MONTH(NOW())
```

To Get Current Year use

```
YEAR(NOW())
```

But you don't need these

Use this-

```
SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM employees 
WHERE (`date` between DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) and CURDATE()) 
AND `status` = 'Pending';
```

Use CURDATE() to get the current date.

To get same date with previous month use:

```
 DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
```

As of now on 25/9/2018

```
SELECT CURDATE()
```

Output:

```
2018-09-25
```

For previous month

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
```

Output:

```
2018-08-25
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raw query you can use procedure, where it will dynamically create date based on your provided date.

DELIMITER $$

-- Call Get_Sum (15)  -- Dynamically you pass the date

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Get_Sum$$

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$

--

### -- Create procedure "Get_Sum"

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE Get_Sum(IN Day SMALLINT)
BEGIN

Declare current_month datetime;
  Declare  previous_month datetime;

Select STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year(now()),'-',month(NOW()),'-',Day), '%Y-%m-%d') INTO current_month;

Select DATE_SUB(current_month, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) into previous_month;

SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM employees 
 WHERE (`date` between previous_month and current_month ) AND `status` = 'Pending';

END
$$

DELIMITER ;